# Hive/Hbase integration : configuration problems

Tags: hbase, hive, apache-zookeeper

I am attempting to extract data from our HDFS placed there using thrift/hbase into a Hive table, but I am struggling to find a solution to the following error message;

```
ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation (HConnectionManager.java:checkIfBaseNodeAvailable(751)) 
– Check the value configured in ‘zookeeper.znode.parent’. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

followed by;

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
```

These errors appear in the hive log after running the following query from a hive terminal;

```
create external table d_table (id bigint, date string) 
stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’ 
with serdeproperties (“hbase.columns.mapping” = “:key,a:date”) 
TBLPROPERTIES (“hbase.table.name” = “demo_table”);
```

The table exists, is populated and can be found from within a hbase shell, and I have checked that the HMASTER process is running. The ‘zookeeper.znode.parent’ is set to the default value, and hbase accepts this (if it is changed, hbase will complain, so I am fairly confident that it is correct). I am able to establish a ZK client with no problems.

I have reached the point in researching this problem where I am told the solution is to recompile Hive against the version of HBase I am using, which sort of defies the point of using a distribution. ZK and HBase masters are on the same machine that I am running the HiveQL command from.

If I run the query from another machine, I see the following;

```
ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation 
(HConnectionManager.java:checkIfBaseNodeAvailable(751)) 
– Check the value configured in ‘zookeeper.znode.parent’. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:run(1089)) 
– Session 0×0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper (RecoverableZooKeeper.java:retryOrThrow(219)) 
– Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: 
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = 
ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
```

If I add a property to the hive-site.xml file for zookeeper.quorum, I get the same behaviour as the first machine. I have taken the values for the zookeeper.quorum from Ambari.

I am using the Hortonworks release 1.3 distribution. We have successfully run Hive with HCatalog to create tables etc, and we have run a variety of other scenarios. If further information is needed to help, let me know, I wanted to keep this post clean.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could have a check of zookeeper service port. I am not sure whether you are using an independent zookeeper cluster or not. If not, some other process may have occupied port 2181 and hbase will try to start zookeeper using port 2182. If the service port is not 2181, Hive will complain without specific configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error while communicating with Hbase in java.
It did get resolved when I added the following conf.

```
conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
```

Hope that helps